# SonarQube Code Coverage Could not account for Kotlin files on an Android Project

Tags: android, kotlin, sonarqube, jacoco

Below is my sonarqube properties snippet:

```
sonarqube {
   properties{
      property "sonar.junit.reportPaths", "build/test-results/testDebugUnitTest/*.xml"
      property("sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "build/reports/jacocoTestReport.xml"
}
}
```

Jacoco configuration and properties are working fine, how did I confirm this?
I created a java class and wrote a unit test for it, sonarqube recognises this and recorded it as part of the Code Coverage, while it basically ignore all the Kotlin file test.
I went ahead to change a kotlin file to java and also write a UnitTest for it and yes, it got recorgnised and add as part of the Code Coverage, again, the kotlin file tests were ignored.

Below is my Jacoco.gradle by the way:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

ext {
    coverageExclusions = [
            '**/*Activity*.*',
            '**/*Fragment*.*',
            '**/R.class',
            '**/R$*.class',
            '**/BuildConfig.*',
    ]
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = '0.8.6'
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports")
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
    jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
}


tasks.withType(Test) {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest']) {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports for Debug build"

    reports {
        xml.enabled(true)
        html.enabled(true)
        xml.destination(file("build/reports/jacocoTestReport.xml"))
    }

    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug/classes", excludes: coverageExclusions)
    def mainSrc = "/src/main/java"

    additionalSourceDirs.from = files(mainSrc)
    sourceDirectories.from = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories.from = files([debugTree])

    executionData.from = fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
            'jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec', 'outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec'
    ])
```

Comment: When you run your test, does it generates any .exec file? How many? It should be in build/jacoco directory

Comment: Yes it does, just one file testDebugUnitTest.exec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After so much research and debugging, and also with info's from @LarryX answer above, I was able to play around the classes as he said, below is my working `Jacoco.gradle` file.

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.4"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
    jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    (android.hasProperty('applicationVariants')
            ? android.'applicationVariants'
            : android.'libraryVariants')
            .all { variant ->
                def variantName = variant.name
                def unitTestTask = "test${variantName.capitalize()}UnitTest"
                def androidTestCoverageTask = "create${variantName.capitalize()}CoverageReport"

                tasks.create(name: "${unitTestTask}Coverage", type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: [
                        "$unitTestTask",
                        "$androidTestCoverageTask"
                ]) {
                    group = "Reporting"
                    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports for the ${variantName.capitalize()} build"

                    reports {
                        html.enabled(true)
                        xml.enabled(true)
                        csv.enabled(true)
                    }

                    def excludes = [
                            // data binding
                            'android/databinding/**/*.class',
                            '**/android/databinding/*Binding.class',
                            '**/android/databinding/*',
                            '**/androidx/databinding/*',
                            '**/BR.*',
                            // android
                            '**/R.class',
                            '**/R$*.class',
                            '**/BuildConfig.*',
                            '**/Manifest*.*',
                            '**/*Test*.*',
                            'android/**/*.*',
                            // butterKnife
                            '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                            '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
                            // dagger
                            '**/*_MembersInjector.class',
                            '**/Dagger*Component.class',
                            '**/Dagger*Component$Builder.class',
                            '**/*Module_*Factory.class',
                            '**/di/module/*',
                            '**/*_Factory*.*',
                            '**/*Module*.*',
                            '**/*Dagger*.*',
                            '**/*Hilt*.*',
                            // kotlin
                            '**/*MapperImpl*.*',
                            '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                            '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
                            '**/BuildConfig.*',
                            '**/*Component*.*',
                            '**/*BR*.*',
                            '**/Manifest*.*',
                            '**/*$Lambda$*.*',
                            '**/*Companion*.*',
                            '**/*Module*.*',
                            '**/*Dagger*.*',
                            '**/*Hilt*.*',
                            '**/*MembersInjector*.*',
                            '**/*_MembersInjector.class',
                            '**/*_Factory*.*',
                            '**/*_Provide*Factory*.*',
                            '**/*Extensions*.*',
                            // sealed and data classes
                            '**/*$Result.*',
                            '**/*$Result$*.*'
                    ]

                    def javaClasses = fileTree(dir: variant.javaCompileProvider.get().destinationDir,
                            excludes: excludes)
                    def kotlinClasses = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/${variantName}",
                            excludes: excludes)

                    classDirectories.setFrom(files([
                            javaClasses,
                            kotlinClasses
                    ]))

                    def variantSourceSets = variant.sourceSets.java.srcDirs.collect { it.path }.flatten()
                    sourceDirectories.setFrom(project.files(variantSourceSets))

                    def androidTestsData = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/outputs/code_coverage/${variantName}AndroidTest/connected/", includes: ["**/*.ec"])

                    executionData(files([
                            "$project.buildDir/jacoco/${unitTestTask}.exec",
                            androidTestsData
                    ]))
                }

            }
}
```

Take note of :

```
  def javaClasses = fileTree(dir: variant.javaCompileProvider.get().destinationDir,
                        excludes: excludes)
                def kotlinClasses = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/${variantName}",
                        excludes: excludes)

                classDirectories.setFrom(files([
                        javaClasses,
                        kotlinClasses
                ]))
```

Also, take note of `project.afterEvaluate` I'm not sure this is relevant but cause I think you must have run and generated your test before this section runs anyways.
This solution also works for a library if not an actual android application.

And then my `sonarqube.gradle` file below.

```
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

    sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000/"
            property "sonar.projectKey", "fair"
            property "sonar.projectName", "fair"
            property "sonar.login", "de9d79fe4d3aef9879567afc91a2ce465038d9be"
            property "sonar.projectVersion", "${android.defaultConfig.versionName}"
    
            property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-results/testDebugUnitTest"
            property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
            property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
            property "sonar.android.lint.report", "build/reports/lint-results.xml"
            property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", "build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"
            property "sonar.jacoco.itReportPath", fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes: ["**/*.ec"])
            property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "build/reports/jacoco/testDebugUnitTestCoverage/testDebugUnitTestCoverage.xml"
        }
    }
    tasks.sonarqube.dependsOn ":app:testDebugUnitTestCoverage"
```

Finally my `build.gradle(project)`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32"
        classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.7"
        classpath("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.3")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check jacoco config for java + kotlin project:

http://vgaidarji.me/blog/2017/12/20/how-to-configure-jacoco-for-kotlin-and-java-project/

Key is to include kotlin directories in sourceDirectories and classeDirectories

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I was able to get it to work by playing around with just what you said and It working now, I will also post it as an answer.